# sliding image in background while the text and button remains static

Tags: carousel, sliding

Please am trying to create a front page with a sliding image and the text and button on it remain in same position while images slide underneath the text and button..
solution i found online are not helpful

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is setting the content you want to remain static to fixed. Place all the content inside a wrapper so you dont need to manually position each element.

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.container img{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.fixed {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="fixed">
    <p class="lead" style="color: white;">Hello! I'm text.</p>
    <button class="btn">PRESS</button>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="https://cdn.stocksnap.io/img-thumbs/960w/ZJSCDFRHOO.jpg" alt="Image" style="width:100%;">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://cdn.stocksnap.io/img-thumbs/960w/ZJSCDFRHOO.jpg" alt="Image" style="width:100%;">
      </div>
    
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://cdn.stocksnap.io/img-thumbs/960w/ZJSCDFRHOO.jpg" alt="Image" style="width:100%;">
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```